# redirect function setted to refresh doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I'm building a jquery mobile site and using codeigniter.I build a login and main page.I used `redirect` function but setted it to refresh, doesn't allow to load correctly main page. Setted it to 'location' load the main page correctly but the URL remain that of login page even if I login correctly and show main page.I should see in the url the main page controller

[image]

### Login Controller

```
    <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Description of login_form
 *
 * @author apocalipse89
 */
class Login extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('User','user'); /* This call the model to retrieve data from db */
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if(!file_exists('application/views/_login.php'))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<h4 style="text-align:center;">','</h4>');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','username','trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','password','trim|required|xss_clean|callback_pass_check');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            /* Data to pass to view */
            $data['title'] = "User Access";
            $data['author'] = "Salvatore Mazzarino";
            $data['year'] = date('Y');

            $this->load->view('templates/_header',$data);
            $this->load->view('_login',$data);
           /* $this->load->view('templates/_footer',$data);*/
        }
        else 
        {   
            redirect('home','refresh');
        }
    }

    public function pass_check($pass)
    {        
        $result = $this->user->find_user($this->input->post('username'),$pass);

        if(!empty($result))
        {            
                $session_array = array('id'=> $result->id, 'username'=> $result->username); /* Create a session passing user data */

                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_array);

                return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('pass_check',"Invalid username or password!</br>Try again, please!");
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}

/* END OF FILE */
```

### Home Controller

```
  <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * Description of home
 *
 * @author apocalipse89
 */
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {        
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {                        
            $data['title'] = "Management Emergency";
            $data['author'] = "Salvatore Mazzarino";
            $data['year'] = date('Y');

            $this->load->view('templates/_header', $data);
            $this->load->view('_home',$data);
            $this->load->view('templates/_footer',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('home');
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
        redirect('home');
    }
}

/* END OF FILE */
```

Comment: does it exist a way that could substitute redirect ? I'm having problem with codeigniter

Comment: the redirect() function is little more than a wrapper for the header() php function. Is error reporting enabled? do you have any output before you call the redirect?

Comment: yeah...error reporting is enabled. I have the login page and when I click on login button it doesn't redirect to main page but show me an undefined gray page write on undefined.But If I use redirect setted to location it works (the main page opens correctly) but the URL points to login page. instead should point to main page

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: as I said if redirect is setted to refresh, I receive a gray page that show me the word`undefined`.

Comment: I think to resolve this problem It need a good knowledge of javascript

Comment: @DamienPirsy I posted a pic of what I see

Comment: javascript? what does it have to do with the redirect()? What's the code you're using?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7730/discussion-between-mazzy-and-damien-pirsy)

Comment: Well If I didn't use jquery mobile and load the page normally, everything works even if redirect is setted to refresh. Instead loading page with jquery mobile and redirect setted to location well it works but there are problems with URL. So I think the redirect function goes in conflict with javascript behaviour

Comment: @Christian But my code is very long since I'm using MVC architecture

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with the slashes as the documentation says?

```
redirect('/home/','refresh');
```

**Note:** In order for this function to work, it must be used before anything is outputted to the browser since it utilizes server headers.

**Note:** For very fine grained control over headers, you should use the Output Library's `set_header()` function.

Documentation: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html